# In Twilio Message body contains other than english text it is getting replaced with?

Tags: java, twilio

In Twilio Message body contains other than english text it is getting replaced with ? please help.

Comment: Hi, you need to show some code, what encoding you are using ?

Comment: Also, I suggest opening a ticket with Twilio via the Twilio Console or help@twilio.com with the details and SMS SID's with the stated issue.

Comment: HI ...... Below is the code i am using there messageCreator

Comment: message = Message.creator(new com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber(convertPhoneNumberToE16Format(toAccountId)),
     new com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber(convertPhoneNumberToE16Format(msgRequest.getFromAccountId())),
     msgRequest.getMsgText());                                                            
                                                                                                                                
         here in   msgRequest.getMsgText() if i pass string which is not english i am recieving  as string replaced by ?......@VilsadPP  please help me